# Rebuild this JSON Object with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

At the moment my JSON object looks like this:

```
[
  ["GB", "gib", "gigabyte", "gigabytes"],
  ["MB", "mib", "megabyte", "megabytes"],
  ["Television", " Televisions", " TV", " TVs"],
  ["tryouts", "tryout", "tests", "test", "trial", "experiment"],
  ["football", "soccer", "Fussball"]
];
```

What I would like to see in the end is a new object that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    synonyms: "GB, gib, gigabyte, gigabytes"
  },
  {
    synonyms: "MB, mib, megabyte, megabytes"
  },
  {
    synonyms: "Television, Televisions, TV, TVs"
  },
  {
    synonyms: "tryouts, tryout, tests, test, trial, experiment"
  },
  {
    synonyms: "football, soccer, Fussball"
  }
];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this with [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
var output = [];
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    output.push({
        synonyms: input[i].join(', ');
    });
}
```

Where the first array you posted is known as `input`.

Answer (score 2):

Solution with `.map()`:

```
var myArray = [
    ["GB", "gib", "gigabyte", "gigabytes"],
    ["MB", "mib", "megabyte", "megabytes"],
    ["Television", " Televisions", " TV", " TVs"],
    ["tryouts", "tryout", "tests", "test", "trial", "experiment"],
    ["football", "soccer", "Fussball"]
];

var synonymArray = myArray.map(function(list) {
    return {
        synonyms: list.join(", ")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this easily with the method map (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
input = [
  ["GB", "gib", "gigabyte", "gigabytes"],
  ["MB", "mib", "megabyte", "megabytes"],
  ["Television", " Televisions", " TV", " TVs"],
  ["tryouts", "tryout", "tests", "test", "trial", "experiment"],
  ["football", "soccer", "Fussball"]
];

output = input.map(function(d) {return {'synonyms':d.join(', ')};});

document.write(JSON.stringify(output));
console.log(output);
```

here is a fiddle with it https://jsfiddle.net/bukart/pg6b3evr/

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop and join:

```
var newObject = [];
for (var i in originalArray) {
  var originalItem = originalArray[i];
  var textList = originalItem.join(',');
  newObject.push({synonyms:textList});
}
```

Working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/v7a3xp7r/4/

Answer (score 1):

ES6:

```
[
  ["GB", "gib", "gigabyte", "gigabytes"],
  ["MB", "mib", "megabyte", "megabytes"],
  ["Television", " Televisions", " TV", " TVs"],
  ["tryouts", "tryout", "tests", "test", "trial", "experiment"],
  ["football", "soccer", "Fussball"]
].map(i => ({synonyms:i.join(', ')}))
```

Comment: very nice short version